# React Project build fails on Aws amplify while updated from React v16 to v18

Tags: reactjs, deployment, aws-amplify

I have recently updated my react project from **React v16 to v18**. It builds on my local machine using `npm run build`. But after deploying in ***Aws Amplify*** to build it gives error! Throwing whole log below. Is it something from npm error or ***While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4*** on the log showed so?

```
2022-12-14T10:37:14.709Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm install
2022-12-14T10:37:19.882Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! code
2022-12-14T10:37:19.884Z [WARNING]: ERESOLVE
2022-12-14T10:37:19.904Z [WARNING]: npm
2022-12-14T10:37:19.904Z [WARNING]: ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
                                npm ERR!
                                npm ERR!
2022-12-14T10:37:19.904Z [WARNING]: While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
                                npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
                                npm ERR! node_modules/react
                                npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
2022-12-14T10:37:19.904Z [WARNING]: npm ERR!   peerOptional react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || 
^18.0.0" from @apollo/client@3.7.2
                                npm ERR!   node_modules/@apollo/client
                                npm ERR!     @apollo/client@"^3.3.14" from the root 
                                project
                                npm ERR!     @apollo/client@"latest" from @apollo/react- 
components@4.0.0
                                npm ERR!     node_modules/@apollo/react-components
                                npm ERR!       @apollo/react-components@"^4.0.0-beta.2" 
from the root project
                                npm ERR!   33 more (@aws-amplify/ui-react, ...)
                                npm ERR!
                                npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
                                npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material- 
ui/core@4.12.4
2022-12-14T10:37:19.905Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
                                npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.11.3" from the root 
project
                                npm ERR!
                                npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
                                npm ERR! node_modules/react
                                npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from 
@material-ui/core@4.12.4
                                npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
                                npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.11.3" from the root 
 project
                                npm ERR!
                                npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
                                npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer- 
deps
                                npm
2022-12-14T10:37:19.905Z [WARNING]: ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) 
dependency resolution.
                                npm ERR!
                                npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full 
report.
2022-12-14T10:37:19.906Z [WARNING]: 
2022-12-14T10:37:19.906Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-14T10_37_14_924Z- 
debug-0.log
2022-12-14T10:37:19.918Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2022-12-14T10:37:19.918Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2022-12-14T10:37:19.918Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2022-12-14T10:37:19.918Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2022-12-14T10:37:20.001Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2022-12-14T10:37:20.001Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use React 18, you should use it with @mui/material v5 instead of @material-ui/core.
https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/overview/